# Error after running macro on another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a remote macro but I'm getting an error "**Close method of Workbook class failed**" when closing the workbook. What do I need to change?

```
Sub RunRemoteMacro()
    Dim xlApp, xlWbk

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("anotherworkbook.xlsm", , True)

    xlApp.Application.Visible = True

    xlApp.Application.Run "testmacro"

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' ERROR: Close method of Workbook class failed
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    xlWbk.Close False

exitHandler:
    xlApp.Application.Quit

    Set xlWkb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    Debug.Print Now() & ": RunRemoteMacro - " & Err.Description

    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: is this vba being run within excel or is it in another microsoft application?

Comment: what is `testmacro` doing?

Comment: Is `xlWbk` still open when it errors?

Comment: where is `testmacro` placed?

Comment: I' m trying to run this VBA from Excel, Outlook and vbs script (error is the same!);

Comment: testmacro is placed in an excel file "anotherworkbook.xlsm" and for now is just showing a message. When I click "OK" the macro finishes and "RunRemoteMacro"should continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way to close properly. See code in **exitHandler**.

```
Sub RunRemoteMacro()
    Dim xlApp, xlWbk

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("anotherworkbook.xlsm", , True)

    xlApp.Application.Visible = True

    xlApp.Application.Run "testmacro"

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False   

exitHandler:
    ' Close Workbook
    xlWbk.Close False
    Set xlWkb = Nothing

    ' Close application
    xlApp.Application.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    Debug.Print Now() & ": RunRemoteMacro - " & Err.Description

    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```